# VisualSVN repository backup file format

Tags: svn, backup, visualsvn

I am running a script to backup the repository. Basically the script runs svnadmin dump command. Which file format I need to choose. If anything wrong happen with the repository how can I restore it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`svnadmin dump` creates a backup that is guaranteed to be supported by newer versions of svn and can be loaded with `svnadmin load` into a new repository.

`svnadmin hotcopy` creates a complete/exact copy of the repository and is only guaranteed to work with the exact same version of svn.  Newer versions of svn may not be able to read the hotcopy.  The advantage though is hotcopy is faster and can be restored simply by copying the hotcopy into place to restore.

We use hotcopy at our office.